# Android Cordova 5.3.3 error when deploying .APK file to device

Tags: android, cordova, package

I have a Cordova 5.3.3 Android application, which works fine if I deploy it directly to my device through eclipse (Run As Android Application). But when I export the application and try to run the .apk on a device, it immediately crashes. I submitted the application to the Play Store and the same happened.

I had my console open and it showed the following error:

[image]

I can find my MainActivity package located in the `src` at `com.ontrac.nutshellmobile`.

Any idea why this is showing up?

Comment: Did you try clearing your phone's `Dalvik Cache` ?

Comment: No, but I have tried this on multiple devices and I still get the same problem

Comment: If you are using an `External Library`, kindly check if it is on path while the `APK` is imported.

Comment: @Pooshonk did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @SMT yeah it was as Lance said, the external library was in the incorrect place.